# cakephp limit access to login screen when logged in

Tags: php, cakephp

I don't want my users to be able to go to the login page if they are logged in. They have to log out first to be able to login. It seems simple enough, am i not understanding something correctly

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

public function isAuthorized($user) { 

    if( $this->Auth->login() ){ 
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }

}

public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also actions like register or lost password etc.

Basically you just check on blacklisted controller/actions and redirect to your home screen or login redirect accordingly

```
// Do not allow access to these public actions when already logged in
$allowed = array('Account' => array('login', 'lost_password', 'register'));
foreach ($allowed as $controller => $actions) {
        if ($this->name === $controller && in_array($this->request->action, $actions)) {
                $this->Common->flashMessage('The page you tried to access is not relevant if you are already logged in. Redirected to main page.', 'info');
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
        }
}
```

See
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakefest/blob/master/Controller/AppController.php#L66

Answer (score 0):

I use laravel, and in situations like that, my `login` route is `filter`ed like this.

```
Route::get('login', array('before' => 'guest', "uses" => "SessionController@create"));
```

`guest` is the name of a filter, defined as `return !Auth::check();`

For CakePHP, I'd imagine it'd be pretty similar. Look for a way that you can filter your routes, based on if your current user is authenticated.